# How to replace undefined values with empty string in an array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

Array object:

```
 var jsonList= {
        "list": [{
            "COLUMN_NAME": "control_master_id",
            "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "control_master_id",
            "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "tbi_controls_master",
            "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_widget_controls"
        }, {
            "COLUMN_NAME": "authorization_id",
            "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "authorization_id",
            "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "tbi_authorization_master",
            "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_controls_master"
        }, {
            "COLUMN_NAME": undefined,
            "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": undefined,
            "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": undefined,
            "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_widget_controls "
        }]
    }
```

Expected solution:

```
var jsonList={
    "list": [{
        "COLUMN_NAME": "control_master_id",
        "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "control_master_id",
        "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "tbi_controls_master",
        "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_widget_controls"
    }, {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "authorization_id",
        "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "authorization_id",
        "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "tbi_authorization_master",
        "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_controls_master"
    }, {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "",
        "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "",
        "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "",
        "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_widget_controls "
    }]
}
```

Is there any solution to do this using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)?Any ideas? Elegant solutions?

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. What is producing this? Whatever produced it needs to be fixed

Comment: Which fuction does create your array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for the delay, if you don't care about modifying the existing array and its values then this will probably be a lot quicker performance wise. If you can do anything natively using vanilla js then this should always be used over any libraries in my opinion.

```
jsonList.list.forEach(function(obj) {
  for(var i in obj) { 
    if(obj[i] === undefined) {
      obj[i] = '';
    }
  }
});
```

You can see the latest version on jsbin here https://jsbin.com/xinuyi/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 9):

You can use this

```
var updatedList = JSON.stringify(jsonList.list, function (key, value) {return (value === undefined) ? "" : value});
```

[Demo Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9sxxgy2/)

Comment: Woth noting that [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) returns a string and not an object. You would need to call [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it back to an object.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very quick solution, I haven't benchmarked it but see the solution below or on jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xinuyi/2/edit?html,js,output

```
var jsonList = {
    "list": [{
        "COLUMN_NAME": "control_master_id",
        "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "control_master_id",
        "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "tbi_controls_master",
        "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_widget_controls"
    }, {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "authorization_id",
        "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": "authorization_id",
        "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": "tbi_authorization_master",
        "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_controls_master"
    }, {
        "COLUMN_NAME": undefined,
        "REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME": undefined,
        "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME": undefined,
        "TABLE_NAME": "tbi_widget_controls "
   }]
};

var updatedList = _.map(jsonList.list, function(object, index) {
    return _.mapObject(object, function(val, key) {
        return (val === undefined) ? "" : val;
    });  
});
```

Comment: No worries, if you don't care about editing the existing array you could use javascript's native each method which would be faster.

Comment: TypeError: _.mapObject is not a function.. this error im getting after implmenting this logic in my project.

Comment: @SVK the function_.mapObject was added in version 1.8.0. You may be using an older version.